# Flutter: How to always fire a function when a page appears which was already visited

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

Is there a way to always fire a function when visiting a page which was already visited?

I have a page that looks like this:

```
// Loads of imports

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> 
  List<Shift> shifts = [];

  Future<void> getUpcomingShifts() async {
    var shiftList = await ShiftService.upcomingShifts();
    setState(() {
      shifts = shiftList;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getUpcomingShifts();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
        extendBody: true,
        drawer: SideDrawer(),
        body: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Header(title: I18n.of(context).pagesHomeTitle),
          Container(
            child: // The rest of the page
          )
        ]));
  }
}
```

So I want the getUpcomingShifts to always fire when this (home) page is visited. The first time the page is visited this works fine, but after initialization the function never fires again. I can't find any good examples or docs on this matter.

Comment: Maybe you can use `Navigator.pushNamed(.....).then((value) => getUpcomingShifts()) ` or can you elaborate how you go from and to `HomePage`

Comment: @jjchiw Thanks for thinking along here :) Only once i navigate trough `pushReplacementNamed`. All the other times it is `pop`. And when using `pop` there will be no promise.. Also, how do i access a function in the `Widget` i am navigating to?

Comment: I think the `promise/then` should trigger after the `pop` of page that has been pushed from `HomePage`.... `HomPage` -push> `ListData` -pop or back> `HomePage` fires `promise/then` and if you go to `HomePage` with `pushReplacementNamed` the `initState` should trigger `getUpcomingShift`

Comment: It is unclear to me what you mean. Could you maybe write this in a more clear way for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [RouteAware](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RouteAware-class.html) mixin on state and then call your function in the `didPopNext` which gets called when the next route pops off the stack and this page becomes visible again